# I would like to update only one state and return the updated state in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, jwt

I have a nodejs and reactjs web application. Though I am still learning reactjs. I have a system where users login, I captured the user's name, id and token coming from my nodejs: I am using react useContext() to mange the app's state.

Login:

```
dispatch({type: "LOGIN_START"})
        try{
        const response = await axios.post("/auth/login", {
            username: userRef.current.value,
            password: passwordRef.current.value
        });
        console.log(response.data.token)
        dispatch({type:"LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: response.data.user, tokenData:  response.data.token});
       
    }catch(err){
        dispatch({type: "LOGIN_FAILURE"})
    };
```

I saved the `response.data.user` and `response.data.token` in my localstorage.

```
 const INITIAL_STATE = {
 user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
 token: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")) || null,

  export const Context = React.createContext();

  export const ContextProvider = ({children}) =>{
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, INITIAL_STATE);

 //useEffect to enable the user details to be stored in their local storage
   useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user, ));
     localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(state.token, ));
     
  }, [state.user], [state.token]);

  return(
    <Context.Provider value={{
        user:state.user,
        token: state.token,
        dispatch,
    }}>
        {children}
    </Context.Provider>
)
};
```

I created the login action like this which enabled me to capture the user's details and token:

```
export const LoginSucess = (user, token) => ({
type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", 
payload: user,
tokenData: token

 });
```

And the useReducer was written like this:

```
 case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
       return{
        user: action.payload,
         token: action.tokenData,

       };
```

If I want to update the token alone, it does't work as I wanted. Here is the code:

```
  case "UPDATE_TOKEN":
        return{
            ...state,
            token: action.tokenData,
            isFetching: false,
            error: true,
           
        };
```

It just does't update at all. If I remove `...state,` it will update the token but the state.user will become undefined.

If I dont separate the token and user's details during sign-in action, it becomes a problem when the user wants to update their profile. Surely, the user wouldn't be updating their token when updating their profile and this will return user's details without a token. Token is updated via refresh token route or when user logs-in again.
I want to separate the token state from the user's name and id state. The token changes every 15 minutes, needs to have it own state. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create another usecontext and usereducer to handle the token state since it will always change every 15 minutes.